# Insert script to the loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert script to the loaded iframe. Tried this without any luck;

```
document.write('<iframe src ="http://example.com/" width ="100" height ="100">
</iframe>');


document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {

var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("</a>", "</a><scr" + "ipt>
document.write='Hi.......';</sc" + "ript>");
document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;

  }
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
document.write('<iframe src ="http://example.com/" width ="100" height ="100"></iframe>');


        document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].onload = function() {

        var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
        curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("</a>", "</a>"+'<script>'+"document.write=Hi......."+"</sc"+"ript>");
        document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;

          }

</script>
```